# passing a method on an instance of a struct as a parameter

Tags: go

I have a function that accepts a function as a parameter:

```
func send(n int, c func(x int) int) int {
    return c(n)
}
```

and I have a structure with a method defined on it

```
type data struct {
    value int
}

func (t *data) set(x int) {
    t.value = x
}
```

I would like to create an instance of the structure and pass method `set` bound to this instance to the `send` function as the second parameter, to set the `value` field from `send`.

Is this possible?

https://play.golang.org/p/bv1JevQBcq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [method value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values).  Here's something similar to your example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func send(n int, c func(x int)) {
    c(n)
}

type data struct {
    value int
}

func (t *data) set(x int) {
    t.value = x
}

func main() {
    d := data{1}
    fmt.Println(d)
    send(2, d.set)
    fmt.Println(d)
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/-7OoCCcARi)

I could not use the types in the question because the function argument to send returns a value and the method does not. If you do need to use the types in the question, then use an anonymous function to adapt the method to the function argument type:

```
 send(2, func(v int) int { d.set(v); return 0 })
```

Comment: Or make both functions return a value?

Comment: Method Values?! I didn't even know Go had that. Thats awesome. Thanks a lot!